# Use a function in ng-class in angular js

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, angularjs

I am using `ng-class` for adding the CSS classes. Even though there are lots articles on this, I am not able to add a function call with `ng-class`.

I have a following expression.

```
ng-class="{'highlighter-row-Class' : (file.id == 1 && file.processed),
    'bold-row-Class' : lastSelectedResumeId == file.attributes.name, 
    'failed-doc': !file.processed}"
```

Now, multiple classes can get added. However, I want to add one more condition here, which will call a method and return a class name:

```
$scope.getclass = function() {
  return 'someclass';
}
```

My attempt used this method in `ng-class` after the last condition, but it wasn't working. So, can anyone please tell me how I can do it correctly with `ng-class`?

---

#### Another attempt (after suggestions):

```
ng-class="[{'highlighter-row-Class' : (file.id == 1 && file.processed),
    'bold-row-Class' : lastSelectedResumeId == file.attributes.name, 
    'failed-doc': !file.processed }, getClassForHrms(file)]"
```

#### Function:

```
$scope.getClassForHrms = function (file) {
    if (file.attributes.hrmsMandatoryFieldsMissing) {
        return "missingfieldspresent";
    } else if (file.attributes.isDocumentDuplicated) {
        return "documentduplicate";
    } else if (!file.attributes.isDocumentDuplicated) {
        return "documentuploadfailed";
    }
};
```

#### Used CSS:

```
.missingfieldspresent {
  color: red;
}
.documentduplicate {
  color: purple;
}
.documentuploadfailed {
  color: deeppink;
}
```

This is what the resulted HTML renders

```
<tr ng-repeat="file in processResumeFiles" ng-class="[{'highlighter-row-Class' : (file.id == 1 &amp;&amp; file.processed), 
    'bold-row-Class' : lastSelectedResumeId == file.attributes.name, 
    'failed-doc': !file.processed }, getClassForHrms(file)]" 
    class="ng-scope [object Object] documentduplicate">
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Passing function with parameters in ng-class to get the class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28208165/passing-function-with-parameters-in-ng-class-to-get-the-class)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28208165/passing-function-with-parameters-in-ng-class-to-get-the-class

Comment: Yes I know this, I tried this as well, But Please look at my question I am saying how to use that in my ng-class

Comment: Have you tried interpolation i.e. `class="{{ getclass() }}"`?

Comment: Yes I tried that also

Comment: Hey, I tried this but here that class is not getting added to class  it is returning the value as well

Comment: **Divide and conquer.** When you have a small amount of code, but the source of the problem is entirely unclear, start removing code a bit at a time until the problem disappears – then add the last part back.

Answer (score 1):

You need an **array** of classes, where one element of an array can be an object of classes with conditions and the other is your function call. A *simple* example would be:

```
ng-class="[{'some_class' : condition}, function_class()]"
```

Here is a demo:

```js
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
app.controller('myCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.bb = function() {
    return "b";
  }
});
```

```css
.a {
  color: #999999;
}

.b {
  background-color: #F1F1F1;
}

.c {
  font-size: 30px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.9/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl">

  <br><input type="checkbox" ng-model="aa" /> A: color : #999999
  <br><input type="checkbox" ng-model="cc" /> C: font-size : 30px

  <div ng-class="[ bb(), {'a':aa, 'c':cc} ]">
    <p>Testing classes</p>
  </div>

</div>
```

---

For your example I think you need:

```
ng-class="[{'highlighter-row-Class' : (file.id == 1 && file.processed) 
        ,'bold-row-Class' : lastSelectedResumeId == file.attributes.name, 
       'failed-doc': !file.processed}, getclass()]"
```

Comment: Classes are not getting applied now, and even the method is not getting called.

Comment: Actually I tried console log now method is getting called but its not applying the classes .

Comment: Beware classes in CSS are case insensitive and classes in HTML are case sensitive. This can cause mismatches.

Comment: Hey it is adding classes but only addinng those which are from the method. and one class is getting added which is like [object object]

Comment: Actually, the [object object] is the class which is getting applied , but its in array so How can I use this now

Comment: @ganeshkaspate looks like a bug. `ng-class` [accepts strings and objects](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngClass#overview). But your object is converted to a string, so after applying `.toString()` it is replaced with `[object Object]`. What **version** of AngularJS are you using?

Comment: 1.5 is the version

Comment: looks like https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33481415/angularjs-ng-class-not-working-when-expression-array-with-object-and-string

Comment: Then Is there any solution for this ?

Comment: @ganeshkaspate a hack would be to check for your conditions within a controller and append then into one big string that you can insert into `ng-class`